# Im looking for a HP fanfic where Sirius has a daughter

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Sirius has a daughter and he used that card to not get arrested and raised her. They're close with the Malfoys. When she went to Hogwarts (I think she was in Slytherin) she was being bullied by Gryffindors and Remus didn't like her because they all thought that Sirius was the traitor. At first Harry liked her but, because of the others whispering bad things about her, he started hating her. They bashed her a lot.

When it was revealed that Sirius was not the traitor, Harry stayed in Grimmauld Place for a vacation (I think) and the daughter felt that she was being replaced. Because it was like Sirius only cared for Harry. (I cried when she threw a ring that Sirius gave to her)

I've been looking for it and I don't know the ending because I haven't finished it yet and forgot the pairing. I last read it pre-pandemic.

Answer (score 2):

It's called **"[Betrayal of the Black](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/59341764-betrayal-of-the-black)"** (2020) by -beths and it's on Wattpad.

From Goodreads:

> The Boy Who Lived, The Chosen One, Harry James Potter. When Harry discovered that Sirius Black was his legal guardian, his life was flipped around. He finally had a parental figure and Sirius was willing to do anything for him.
>
> Celestia Faith Black, daughter of the infamous Sirius Black, second best to Harry Potter. After discovering her father was innocent of all crimes, she wanted to get closer with him. But that tends to be a lot harder when your father favours his godson more than you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct fanfic, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.